# Taking spare parts from a thrown away bike

Tags: theft, ownership

Alice takes a walk outside everyday and passes a bike just lying around, which is clearly not in a location where people would normally leave their bike (cycle rack, near a store or a bus stop, ... ) and it is not locked. She concludes the bike was thrown away. The bike is in a bad condition, but some parts are still good.

Does she commit a crime if she takes some spare parts from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the legality of an individual of dismantling very clearly abandoned bikes locked to fixtures and fences in a public area?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/62062/what-is-the-legality-of-an-individual-of-dismantling-very-clearly-abandoned-bike)  Although the duplicate is tagged New York, *we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]*". From the [Help centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)